# Animating an algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael, sleep

I am using Raphael.js to visualize a convex hull algorithm. 
However I want to be able to step through the different parts of the code (or use something like sleep()/delay()). However, I can't see a way of accomplishing this using setTimeOut(). Any ideas?

For example:

```
sort(points);
//sleep(...)/delay(...)/pause until click?
for(...) {
   message('Foo thing');
   //sleep(...)/delay(...)/pause until click?
   while() {
      message('Comparing points');
      //sleep(...)/delay(...)/pause until click?
   }
}
```

[image: A screenshot of the result of the algorithm. Points in red indicate an element of the convex hull.]

Comment: Without more explanations on what you mean by `step through the different parts of the code`, and without seeing your code, not many, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you mean you're looking for modal message boxes, like the ones created by `alert()`?

Comment: No, that is a function (which I defined) that updates an HTML element with the step the algorithm is executing.

Comment: See my screenshot above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript there is no way to suspend code execution with `sleep` function. Executing JavaScript code is designed to be non-blocking.

Solution with using `debugger` keyword works on Chrome as well. You just have to open Developer Tools.

I prepared demo which works in different way. It simulates `sleep` function using `setInterval` and does not block scripts execution. However, it involves some additional code.

Let's assume that we have initial code:

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

function step(val) {
    console.log(val);
}

for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    step(arr[i]);
}
```

Now, we'd like to rewrite it so that each log shows after one second:

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
steps = [];

function step(val) {
  console.log(val);
}

for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
  steps[i] = step.bind(null, arr[i]);
}

var int = setInterval(function() {
    var fun = steps.shift();
    if(!fun) {
        clearInterval(int); 
        return;
    }
    fun();
}, 1000);
```

Let me explain it a little bit. Firstly, I define `steps` array, where I put new functions with bound arguments. `bind` function basically creates new function with arguments which are bound to provided values. More details on [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Example:

```
function step(a) { console.log(a); }
var step1 = step.bind(null, 1);
// now step1 is like `var step1 = function() { console.log(1); }`
```

In `for` loop I create and put new functions using `bind`. The last step is to extract these functions from `steps` array, starting from beginning (using `Array.prototype.shift` method), and execute them with interval equal to 1 second.

I know it's not a direct solution of your problem, but I hope it helps you convert your code properly. If you decide to do so, I advise to convert code blocks within `for` and `while` loops to functions. It simplifies conversion a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could wait for a button click and then when the click has happened you could step one line of code in?

set a onclick listener for the button and set the variable continue = true;
after the piece of code has executed and you want to wait for the next piece of code to run you could use.

```
//code just executed
while(continue == false) sleep(10);
continue = false;
//next code to be executed
while(continue == false) sleep(10);
continue = false;
//more code....
```

there is probably a better solution than this so don't take this code as the best unless its your only answer.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I do not get the idea very clearly.

Comment: javascript has no sleep function, so that won't do it

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the debugging tools available on your browser. If you are on chrome, enable the developer tools by pressing Shift + Ctrl + I. If you are on firefox, you could download install the firebug extension. Once you have done this, you can step through your code by putting in place a breakpoint. This is done by putting the 'debugger;' keyword at the javascript point where you want to begin stepping through. E.g

```
sort(points);
debugger
for(...) {
  message('Foo thing');
  debugger;
  while() {
    message('Comparing points');
    debugger;
  }
}
```